# Not able to see the taxons tree in spree admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, taxonomy

I have just installed spree 3.0.0, and i am exploring the admin menus...

When i click in Taxonomies menu, then click in Categories, i am supposed to see a tree of Taxonomies and Taxons, but i don't (although i am able to see it in my deployed version in heroku)

Locally it looks like :
[image]
And in Heroku it looks like
[image]

I made sure the data exists locally, but dropping/reseeding the database just to be in the safe side, but the problem's still there...

Anyone encountered this problem before ? Any clues ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you load up a rails console and ensure that you have taxonmy/taxon data in your development environment? `Spree::Taxon.count` would be a good start.

Comment: Yes i tried that ! And there are there...

Comment: Can you check your Javascript console and make sure you aren't getting any errors related to your API key? I had issues with this after a recent security fix and ended up having to rewrite a bunch of code to get my API key to take.

Comment: Same/Similar issue. There is no tree and no right click menu for taxons

Comment: Generate api key for your admin user

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the API Key! That was exactly my issue as well and could therefore be resolved. Very much appreciated!